# Disable all select options on page with specific value - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable all options in all select boxes with specific value on page.

If there are 5 select boxes and each have 4 options. Like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

I want to disable all options with value `3` on whole page, how would i achieve this?

```
$("select option["+previous+"]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

But this is disabling `Select option` with selected value **3**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the value of `previous` coming from?

Comment: `"select option[value='"+previous+"']"`?

Comment: @Satpal suggested `$("select option[value="+previous+"]").prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: I like this one: `var previous = 3;
$('select option')
    .filter(function(i, e) { return $(e).val() == previous })
    .prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like whatever you passing treated as a index of inside select. Try value attribute selector

```
$("select option[value ="+previous+"]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: `prop("disabled",true)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using value attribute in jquery.

```
$("select option[value='3']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution using `ES6` template literal

```js
var previous = 3;
$(`select option[value=${previous}]`).prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: ES6 is overkill in my opinion